# How to export SpaCy model with multiple components

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

I'm trying to build a SpaCy pipeline using multiple components. My current pipeline only has two components at the moment, one entity ruler, and another custom component.

The way I build it is like this:

```
class EntityLookupComponent:
    def __call__(self, doc: Doc) -> Doc:
        print("Just testing")
        return doc

@Language.factory("entity_lookup_component")
def my_component(nlp, name):
    return EntityLookupComponent(nlp)

def main(patterns_path: Path, output_path: Path):
    """Build the spaCy model and output it to disk"""

    # Ensure output_path directory exists
    if not Path(os.path.dirname(output_path)).is_dir():
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(output_path))

    nlp = English()
    nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler").from_disk(patterns_path)
    nlp.add_pipe("entity_lookup_component", name="entity_lookup", last=True)

    print(nlp.pipe_names)

    nlp.to_disk('./test')

    with open(output_path, "wb") as output_file:
        pickle.dump(nlp, output_file)
```

Outputting the `pipe_names` gives me: `['entity_ruler', 'entity_lookup']`.

However, when I then try to load the model and test, by doing:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg", disable=["ner"])
nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler", source=spacy.load("./test"))
```

It's instantly throwing me the following error:

```
ValueError: [E002] Can't find factory for 'entity_lookup_component' for language English (en). This usually happens when spaCy calls `nlp.create_pipe` with a custom component name that's not registered on the current language class. If you're using a Transformer, make sure to install 'spacy-transformers'. If you're using a custom component, make sure you've added the decorator `@Language.component` (for function components) or `@Language.factory` (for class components).
```

This only happens after I added the `entity_lookup_component`. This component was supposed to use a lookup table, to add some metadata to existing entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the place where you load the model, you need to have access to the code that defined the custom component. So if your file that defines the custom component is `custom.py`, you can put `import custom` at the top of the file where you're loading your pipeline and it should work.

Also see [the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading#serialization-methods) on saving and loading custom components.

Comment: It was my assumption that when I call `to_disk`, it would serialize the custom component, and save it to disk. So that it could be loaded later on with `spacy.load`. Am I correct in understanding it only saves any data that this component needs, and not the component itself?

Comment: I was able to get it working by importing my component, and doing `nlp.add_pipe("entity_lookup_component", name="entity_lookup", after="entity_ruler")` when I wanted to use it. I assume that the `to_disk` is mostly for preprocessing data used in the model.

Comment: `to_disk` saves component state but doesn't do pickling or other magic (though you can pickle if you want to).